# wait for something to be done before showing the UI

Tags: c#, wpf

so im creating this Application for calculating Profits in a Game and I'm trying to curl something before the UI is shown. It would be really nice if you could help me with the await GetRequest();

I dont know how to do it because i need this to be done before the user can use the App.
GetRequest return a JSON string from which i need to populate objects. If this false I will need to throw an Error to the User(but that is just for the explanation).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        string json = await GetRequest();
        var jsonObjects = JSONDeserialize(json);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Task.WhenAll` Method while waiting for the async to complete
See the following answer. That should resolve the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/14882929

Comment: Ty I will try that